# QnA Knowledge base software

Tags: windows-xp, database, knowledge-management

I'm looking for a small software to build a knowledge base of QnA's on my local PC, like the KBs large software vendors maintain for how-to's regarding their products.

Something where I can:

```
Q: Write my question or issue
A: Write my answer or solution

add, searchable, tags
```

Post programs for any platform, though I'm using Win XP.

Comment: Don't know if you're watching this question anymore, so I'll just put it here. Another one for your collection: http://www.actionoutline.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is gonna sound really naive, but what about @gmail if it's for personal use ?
Or a small application like [CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/) (notes, taggable, searchable) ... maybe OneNote, although that seems overly complicated for this sort of thing.

Or something like [Code Warehouse](http://xcca.com/).

[image]

Anyways, do post if you find a better solution. I'd be interestd to hear about it, expecially if it's a free solution.

Comment: CintaNotes and Code Warehouse is built for QnA's ... good work and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend [Tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/). While the other answers have good apps/webapps for your purpose, they pose a few issues - Tiddlywiki and its feature sets resolves those though:

1. Portable - Tiddlywiki is a standalone web compatible system, move the directory over, launch it in a browser, and you are good to go again.
2. Did I just mention Tiddlywiki runs in a browser? You can't get more lightweight than that.
3. Fully searchable, that supports tags too.
4. Infinitely customizable - Tiddlywiki can and will grow with you as your needs become more complex.
5. If you ever need to take it online, you can just drop it in a server. Best still, set up a sync to a web server and you have your KB where ever you are.
6. It's super-duper fast.
7. You can pretty it up to your own imagination if you know HTML and CSS. You can't do that with an app!

Comment: A desktop app has advantages over a web app ... you don't need a server and its less hassle. The web browser IS NOT the OS. The OS is the OS.

Comment: Erm... tiddlywiki runs off just a browser - no server required.

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd - and I believe most SU folks know the difference between OS and browsers.

Comment: TiddlyWiki is a single html file which has all the characteristics of a wiki - including all of the content, the functionality (including editing, saving, tagging and searching) and the style sheet. Because it's a single file, it's very portable - you can email it, put it on a web server or share it via a USB stick.

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see how it works!

Comment: I did'nt just want a general knowledge base software, but something specifically for QnA's.

Comment: @caliban good comment about it being a single html file -- you should stick that in your answer.

Comment: Given the desired tool will be called on to trouble shoot PC issues, portability is paramount.  That calls for TiddlyWiki.  I use TiddlyWiki for code snippets and a dozen other uses.  It's beautiful.  As for it not being dedicated "Q&A", you'll find a pinch of formatting is all you need to support that function.  Seriously.

Answer (score -1):

I'd look at [Plone](http://plone.org) or any of the wiki tools, personally.

Comment: I was looking for QnA software, and software not web apps, since there are like hundreds of wikis and CMSs.

Comment: yes - and that's exactly what I provided: tools for constructing a knowledge base. I've used both extensively in the past - they are quite widely deployed for such tasks, too.

Answer (score -1):

**Evernote**

- http://www.evernote.com/
- sync with web or other devices (optional)
- fulltext search
- tags

Comment: Original question "on my local PC" .... do you think evernote can function fully offline? not on the cloud?